# Swagger documenting not loading after deploying the Flask app to Nginx web server

Tags: python, nginx, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I wrote REST API gateway using flask-restplus plugin, I tested it locally, and it works using `flask run`.

But when I try to run the website on server, it opens in the browser but Swagger documentation doesn't shows up in browser console. I can see the below error:

[image]

Here is my site nginx configuration:

```
sites-available $ vi clinic_backend 

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name example.com;

        location /static {
            alias /var/www/html/static/;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri @wsgi;
        }

        location @wsgi {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
            include proxy_params;
        }

        location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            expires max;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a [uWSGI config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808952/flask-nginx-and-uwsgi) you can share?

Comment: @brennan I am using gunicorn so I dont need to use uWSGI config file

Comment: Are you using a [ProxyFix](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html)?

Comment: @brennan no I am not using ProxyFix !